# Printing Character Map

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that gives an output of the following table:

```
chr:      !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /  
asc: 32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  
chr:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?  
asc: 48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  
chr:  @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O  
asc: 64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  
chr:  P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _  
asc: 80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  
chr:  `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o  
asc: 96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111  
chr:  p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~    
asc: 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
```

Any help would be appreciated, though I would like to ask to not be given the entire answer, but rather hints, so there is some challenge involved for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Tell us more about your constraints and requirements. As it stands, a single call to `print` with the formatted table already in a string would suffice.

Comment: @Robᵩ My only constraint is that I have to do this via for loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ord` and `chr` functions will help you out:

```
ord('a')  # 97
chr(97)   # 'a'
```

Add to a `range`, and you got a stew going on!

Comment: Well, you want two `range`s (in two nested `for` loops…) but otherwise, this looks likely to be exactly as much info as the OP wants.

Comment: Yep, that's all I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in range(32,128):
    print (i, chr(i))
```

or to be even closer to what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def f(x,y):
    for i in range(x,y):
        print ('%3d '%i,end=''),
    print()
    for i in range(x,y):
        print ('%3s '%chr(i),end='')
    print()
for x in range(32,128,16):
    f(x,x+16)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print '''chr: ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
asc: 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
chr: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ?
asc: 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
chr: @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
asc: 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
chr: P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _
asc: 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
chr: ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
asc: 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111
chr: p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
asc: 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127'''
```

Comment: I considered that, but I was thinking more along the lines of a for loop.  I guess this could work, though.

Comment: In that case, look at Hal Canary's answer

Comment: Clever, but I think wouldn't it be better to use `requests` and `bs4` to read the question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692127/printing-character-map instead of copying and pasting from it? :)

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND His solution printed each result on a new line.

Comment: @user2080719: You explicitly asked not to give you a complete program, just a hint. Hal Canary's answer (and dan.lecocq's as well) has all of the elements you need, and does something similar to but not identical to what you want. How does that not qualify as a good hint?

Comment: @Robᵩ: Post that as an answer. But first make it work; when I go there, I get a errno -2 traceback from `urllib2.urlopen`…

Comment: For obvious reasons, ideone.com don't allow `urlopen` on their site. Download it and run it -- it works.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use loops in the loops with given range thus distinguishing lines as cases. The converted characters may be added as strings together and you only print the line after you have all strings added.

The full code would be:

```
for i in range (2,14): 
 #range(1,13 would have been correct as well, but I want to use the parity)
if i%2==0: #use even numbers for "chr..." line
  a="chr:  "
  for j in range(int((i/2-1)*16+32),int((i/2-1)*16+48)):
#range is a bit complicated due to the i-range
     b=str(chr(j))
#the following ifs are used to regulate space depending on character length
     if len(b)==1:
        s="   "
     if len(b)==2:
        s="  "
     if len(b)==3:
        s=" "
     a=a+b+s #add new characters with space to the previous ones
  print(a)
if i%2==1: #use odd numbers for asc:... line
  a="asc: "
  for j in range(int(((i-1)/2-1)*16+32),int(((i-1)/2-1)*16+48)):
     b=str(j) #in this line you need only the numbers
#the following ifs are used to regulate space depending on character length
     if len(b)==1:
        s="   "
     if len(b)==2:
        s="  "
     if len(b)==3:
        s=" "
     a=a+b+s
  print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good friend gave me this tip, and it works! The remaining thing to do is to adjust placeholders:

```
    for i in range (0, 12):
       if i%2 ==0:
         content ="chr:"
         for j in range (32, 48):
            content=content+"   "+str(chr(j+(i//2)*16))
          print (content)    
        if i%2 ==1:
          content = "asc:"
          for j in range (32, 48):
             content=content+"  "+str(j+(i//2)*16)
          print (content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me as I am just beginning but the following worked for me:

```py
i=32
while i <= 112:
    print ('chr:\t'+chr(i)+'\t'+chr(i+1)+'\t'+chr(i+2)+'\t'+chr(i+3)+'\t'+chr(i+4)+'\t'+chr(i+5)+'\t'+chr(i+6)+'\t'+chr(i+7)+'\t'+chr(i+8)+'\t'+chr(i+9)+'\t'+chr(i+10)+'\t'+chr(i+11)+'\t'+chr(i+12)+'\t'+chr(i+13)+'\t'+chr(i+14)+'\t'+chr(i+15))
    print ('asc:\t'+str(i)+'\t'+str(i+1)+'\t'+str(i+2)+'\t'+str(i+3)+'\t'+str(i+4)+'\t'+str(i+5)+'\t'+str(i+6)+'\t'+str(i+7)+'\t'+str(i+8)+'\t'+str(i+9)+'\t'+str(i+10)+'\t'+str(i+11)+'\t'+str(i+12)+'\t'+str(i+13)+'\t'+str(i+14)+'\t'+str(i+15))
    i=i+16
```

Now I am just trying to create a second loop to take care of the progression/iteration